# E-mail or e-mail or E/email?

Tags: hyphens, capitalization

E-mail or e-mail or E/email? I am finding a variety of content on the proper way to write this term.

Comment: .........not E/Mail.  The others are fine.  You can also use email and Email

Comment: Spelling e-mail with a hyphen is mostly considered archaic these days. I would write 'email' and only capitalise the word if it starts a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

### Nowadays, ‘electronic mail’ is shortened to ‘email’

It's nearly always written as one word *email*, without hyphens, the [compound noun](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound.htm) has become solid for quite some time. But if the OP wants to write it as e-mail or E-mail it isn't wrong, just pick one spelling variant and be consistent.

From [Historical Usage](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/internet) on Dictionary.com,

> The lowercase form internet is regularly used in technology-related publications and in most informal writing such as social media posts, ***email***, and text messages. And lowercase is increasingly being used in formal, edited writing such as newspapers.

further along

> The expression *World Wide Web* over the years has become truncated to the easier-to-say *web* . The term *Hyperlink* , though still in use, has been overtaken by its shortened version, *link*. An *instant message* is more often referred to simply as an IM. In most Internet contexts, the adjective electronic has been shortened to the prefix e- . **So electronic mail has become *email*** (originally e-mail ), and other popular compounds like e-learning , e-wallet , e-signature , and e-commerce have followed suit.

Comment: My son says 'the 1990s called, they want their e hyphen mail back'